# ¿Como agregar un query personalizado en Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Soy nuevo asn ASP.NET MVC 5 y estoy tratando de mudar un proyecto de ASP.NET C# A MVC, pero en mi proyecto anterior tengo consultas larguísimas que involucran hasta 5 tablas con operaciones.

Esta es la consulta que necesito:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Modelo. Esta es mi tabla principal

```
namespace Sistema.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Visitas
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public short IdUser { get; set; }
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public short Campo { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
        public string Estatus { get; set; }
        public string Comentarios { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Clase context. Las demas tablas son las que necesito en mi consulta.

```html
namespace Sistema.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    
    public partial class MyBd : DbContext
    {
        public MyBd()
            : base("name=MyBd")
        {
        }
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Semanas> Semanas { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Usuarios> Usuarios { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Campos> Campos { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Visitas> Visitas { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Lo que intente ahora es es usar Json y Ajax

```html
public JsonResult VisitasList()
{
var visitas = bd.Visitas.SqlQuery("select * from . . . .");
return Json(visitas, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Y con ajax

```html
<script src="~/js/Jquery/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("/Visitas/VisitasList", function (data) {
            console.log('Obtuve los datos');
            $.each(data, function (idx, opt) {
                $('#dataTableVisitas').append('<tr><td>' + opt.colum1 + '</td><td>' + opt.colum2 + '</td><td>' + opt.colum3 + '</td></tr>' + opt.colum4 + '</td></tr>');                
            });
        }, 'json');
    });
</script>
```

Pero me arroja el siguiente error

```html
The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'myContext.Visitas'. A member of the type, 'IdVisita', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.
```

Comment: Pero cual es el problema en particular?

Comment: @gbianchi el problema es que nose como hacer el query en el controller para mostrar los datos en una tabla

Comment: Estas usando EF y no sabes como hacer las consultas esas ahi?

Comment: @gbianchi asi es en la primera imagen muestro el query que necesito, como podrá ver es muy largo

Comment: Entonces la pregunta esta mal formulada y por eso no obtuviste respuestas. Tu pregunta es como agregar un query personalizado en Entity Framework.. puede ser?

Comment: @gbianchi ok ya lo actualice

Comment: Hola, no quiero sonar poco profesional, pero puedes hacer una vista... create View... comprendo pues deseas usar el potencial de índices y tamaños de las tablas, pero mientras averiguo eso puede ser una salida rápida.

Comment: @FabioPalm Hola la tabla en html ya la tengo creada pero el problema es como llenarla, osea como crear el select "personalizado", el query que necesito es el de la primera imagen que he puesto en mi pregunta

Comment: Trampa Paso 1. en tu motor SQL crea la vista; Create View MI_ENTIDAD_REPORTE_1 as Select * from(....)

Comment: Trampa Paso 2. Crea una entidad con todas los campos de la Consulta, la cual será llamada como MI_ENTIDAD_REPORTE_1

Comment: No me gusta pues es muy estático estar creando un modelo por reportes, pero puede ayudarte en la emergencia.

Comment: @FabioPalm mmm y no hay otra alternativa que no sea crear vistas en SQL disculpa?

Comment: Yo hice un ORM ( Object Relational mapping) Pues a mi me gusta usar el SQL para ganar desempeño. pues tenía exactamente el mismo error.

Comment: coincido con la creación de la Vista o también un Procedimiento Almacenado

Comment: @fredyfx y en la vista como cargo los datos?

Comment: igualito, pasando un modelo, creo que este workshop te caerá bien https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta algo así:

```
using (var ctx = new SchoolDBEntities())
{
    //Get student name of string type
    string studentName = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<string>("Select studentname from Student where studentid=1")
                            .FirstOrDefault();

    //or
    string studentName = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<string>("Select studentname from Student where studentid=@id", new SqlParameter("@id", 1))
                            .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Solo que en lugar de un .`FirstOrDefault();` usas un `.ToList();`

Referencia: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx (aunque dice 4.3, la verisón es 6).

Comment: Lo probe List<Visitas> visitas = bd.Visitas.SqlQuery("myquery").ToList(); pero me tira este error 'The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'MyContext.Visitas'. A member of the type, 'IdVisita', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.'

Comment: ¿Has incluído idVisita en la query?

Comment: no, porque no lo necesito

Comment: intenta agregarlo, el error te dice "el miembro IdVisita NO tiene una columna correspondiente con el mismo nombre", por lo tanto... ¿y si le agregas, qué crees que pasaría?

Comment: Lo añadi pero el problema persiste, modifique la primer linea List<string> visitas = bd.Database.SqlQuery<string>("myquery").toList();

Comment: y ahora da el error The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: En lugar de `.SqlQuery<string>` coloca `.SqlQuery<IEnumerable<string>>`

Comment: ahora tira este error The result type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]' may not be abstract and must include a default constructor.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102842/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-huntzberger).

Answer (score 0):

Aún estoy tratando de buscar la forma de Forzar a un Entity Framwork a forzar un Query a que returne un dynamic, creo que esto respondería al problema a conformidad.

```
namespace Sistema.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class EntidadVista
    {
        public int Campo1 { get; set; }
        public int Campo2 { get; set; }
        public int Campo3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

y en el SQL creas lo siguiente:

```
CREATE VIEW EntidadVista as 
Select Campo1 , Campo2, Campo3 FROM (
  SELECT pablito, clavo ,un , clavito FROM la calva INNER JOIN de un calvito
)
```

Esto complementa el ejemplo anterior usando la vista (las vistas son ANSI y la soportan muchos motores).

```
class EntidadVista miRegistroEntidadVista = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<EntidadVista>("Select Campo1 , Campo2, Campo3 from EntidadVista  where 1=1").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: `where 1=1` Creo que tenemos un hacker :D

Answer (score 0):

según entiendo... Sólo necesitas consultar los datos de una tabla con EF no?

Si es así... Es tan sencillo como hacer lo siguiente:

```
public List<Visitas> VisitasList() {
    return bd.Visitas.ToList();
}
```

O si lo quieres filtrado:

```
public List<Visitas> VisitasList(int idUser) {
    return bd.Visitas.Where(x => x.IdUser == idUser).ToList(); // Filtras las visitas de un usuario
}
```

No te hace falta retornar un JSON, y en la parte del front, lo podrás recuperar perfectamente.

Espero te haya ayudado, un saludo!!

Comment: No, la consulta esta en la primera imagen, como verá es una consulta muy compleja y nose como hacerla :c

Comment: Cierto, me fui directamente a la parte donde esperaba tener la consulta que decía: var visitas = bd.Visitas.SqlQuery("select * from . . . .");
ejejeje en otro momento será :)